Why does MS Word show the font style name "Regular" as gibberish?
I recently purchased the Novela font family.  Typst can't distinguish between Regular and Display Regular as they both have the same weight, Italic state (style), and Stretch.
I used fonttools' ttx tool to export Novela Display Regular to a .ttx file, edited it, and then rebuild an .otf file.  The edits consited of making a new Font Family "Novela Display" with styles "Regular" and "Italic".  When I remove all of the fonts and load just the new NovelaDisplay-Regular and NovelaDisplay-Italic, they look good in Font Book, work in Typst, and they do work in word, but when I select Novela Display Regular, I see this:


Where does word get "Display Italic" from?  The .ttx file has:

    <namerecord nameID="1" platformID="1" platEncID="0" langID="0x0" unicode="True">
      Novela Display
    </namerecord>
    <namerecord nameID="2" platformID="3" platEncID="1" langID="0x409">
      Italic
    </namerecord>

and
    <namerecord nameID="16" platformID="3" platEncID="1" langID="0x409">
      Novela Display
    </namerecord>
    <namerecord nameID="17" platformID="3" platEncID="1" langID="0x409">
      Italic
    </namerecord>


Why is Regular shown as garbage?

Interestingly, When I change to use:
    <namerecord nameID="17" platformID="3" platEncID="1" langID="0x409">
      Regular 2
    </namerecord>

Word will show the style as Regular 2.
Or, if I change the Family Name to NovelaDisplay (removing the space), Word will show the Regular style as "Regular" and the Italic style as "Italic".
I'm running macOS Sequoia 15.0.1 (24A348) and Word for Mac Version 16.90 (24101387) (365)

This is not a programming question and, as such, is off-topic for Stack Overflow. See: https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic. Questions on general usage of Microsoft Word should be asked on an appropriate end-use forum (e.g., MS Answers).
